Rescheduled flight by 10 hours with no cancellation option yet
I booked a flight from London Luton to Vilnius for next June. Departure time was 16:10. A few days I glanced at the app to see my flight time is now 6:15. This is an inconvenient time for me to get to the airport to. I saw another airline had cheap flights at 8:00on the same day. There was no cancellation option available on the Ryanair website or app. When I contacted them through the website they informed me the email informing customers of cancellation is sent 90 days before and I was also told I could not apply for a refund till this time. They also stated flight times are not final and still might change. How can I get a refund from Ryanair now and not in many months?

I’m not sure you can. How much is the alternative flight? If it’s cheap and you don’t want to wait it out until Ryanair finalises its flight schedule, you could hedge your bets and book the alternative. Although this far in advance there’s no guarantee that airline won’t do the same thing.

10 hours is clearly a "significant schedule" change and you are entitled to a full refund. You need to call Ryan Air and be persistent. You may have to threaten filing a complaint with the applicable local authorities.
